# $P(x)$ is odd degree polynomial and is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.$P(x)|Q(x)^2+Q(x)R(x)+R(x)^2.$Prove that $P(x)^2|Q(x)^2+Q(x)R(x)+R(x)^2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $P(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $\text{deg}(P)$ is **odd**.
$Q(x),R(x)$ are polynomials with rational coefficients satisfying $$P(x)|Q(x)^2+Q(x)R(x)+R(x)^2.$$Prove that $$P(x)^2|Q(x)^2+Q(x)R(x)+R(x)^2.$$

I found this problem in aops.com but it’s in the old post which is now already locked and no one solved it yet in that post so I will post it here.
I tried to use the fact that $P(x)$ has at least one real root and it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. Also $P(x)\mid Q(x)^3-R(x)^3$ look like a good thing to consider but I don’t know how to continue from here.

Btw. I only want some hints **not a full solution**.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? And where did you find this problem?

Comment: I am new here so do I have to include that in the body?

Comment: Yes please. See also [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), especially the first bullet point.

Comment: It actually has a solution on AoPS, but since you don't want a solution, as a start try to use that odd degree polynomial will always have a real root...

Comment: I think I get something. Let $P(m)=0$ when $m$ is real nember. Then I got that $Q(m)=R(m)=0$.
How to continue from here?

Comment: That's correct, now you need to use this to show that $P(x) \mid Q(x)$, $P(x) \mid R(x)$ (hint: $P(x)$ is irreducible!)